# Infimum of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Does $\inf(E)$ exist in a case such as the following?

$$E = \{r \in \mathbb{Q} | r < \sqrt{12}\}$$

I know that we can construct sets which upper bound the integers, but which have no least upper bound on the integers. I assume this is also the case for lower bounds of all rational numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the set $E=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}| r<\sqrt{12}\}$ has no lower bound, it also cannot have an infimum, (greatest lower bound). However if you are looking for a supremum (least upper bound), then $\sup (E)=\sqrt{12}.$ This is easy to prove, since $\sqrt{12}$ is clearly both an upper bound and a limit point of the set $E.$

Comment: Thanks! Question, though. Doesn't sup(E) not exist, since $\sqrt{12}$ isn't in Q?

Comment: I assumed you were thinking of your set $E$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}.$ But as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ you are right, there is no supremum. This is actually the critical difference between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. The set $\mathbb{R}$ has the completeness property, that all sets with upper bounds have supremums, while $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have this property. The real numbers were actually specifically designed to be complete, because complete sets are often much nicer to work with than incomplete sets.